# append a dictionary like structure to a dictionary python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list like this : 372 374 375 533 849 1057 734 640 853 2 672 581 352 384 386 505 421 372 374 375 734 1354 1355
I am trying to build a dictionary that mentions which number follow a certain number and how many times the repetition has been repeated.

i.e.
['372':('374',2),'375':('533',1), ('734',1)......]

so the key is all the items and the value is a list of tuples or a list of dictionary if that is more appropriate for accessing. I've tried to build a dictionary that has the first occurrence of the numbers as keys and the values that are immediately after that as its values, but since they are strs, I cannot append to them. Is there any way to define the dictionary to match this structure?

```
for i,j in zip(xrange(0,len(IDs)), xrange(1,len(IDs))):
    if not IDs[i] in mydict:
        mydict[IDs[i]]=IDs[j]
    else:
        mydict[IDs[i]].append(IDs[j])
```

I really appreciate your guidance.

Answer (score 1):

```
from collections import defaultdict
ids = [372, 374, 375, 533, 849, 1057, 734, 640, 853, 2, 672, 581, 352, 384, 386, 505, 421, 372, 374, 375, 734, 1354, 1355]
mydict = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))
for i in xrange(len(ids)-1):
    mydict[ids[i]][ids[i+1]] += 1
```

Example output:

```
>>>mydict[372]
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {374: 2})
```

Comment: yes because I want to see which IDs comes after a certain ID and how many times did it happen for each of them.

Comment: OK, I reread your question and edited my answer. It should be what you are looking for now.

Answer (score 0):

As you are expecting **each number** as **key** and number followed by and its **count** in tuple.

But as for example number **734** which is followed both **640** and **1354**.

And we can't have `734:(640, 1), 734:(1354, 1)` as output **dict** because we can't have *duplicate keys*.

So this might be one of the possible solution.

```
my_list = [372, 374, 375, 533, 849, 1057, 734, 640, 
           853, 2, 672, 581, 352, 384, 386, 505, 
           421, 372, 374, 375, 734, 1354, 1355]

from collections import Counter           
result = Counter(zip(my_list[:-1], my_list[1:]))
print result
```

**Yields**:

```
Counter({
            (374, 375): 2, 
            (372, 374): 2, 
            (375, 734): 1, 
            (352, 384): 1, 
            (1354, 1355): 1, 
            (505, 421): 1, 
            (734, 1354): 1, 
            (853, 2): 1, 
            (849, 1057): 1, 
            (384, 386): 1, 
            (2, 672): 1, 
            (421, 372): 1, 
            (375, 533): 1, 
            (672, 581): 1, 
            (581, 352): 1, 
            (533, 849): 1, 
            (1057, 734): 1, 
            (640, 853): 1, 
            (386, 505): 1, 
            (734,640): 1
                          })
```

And you can get count for pairs like:

```
print "(374, 375): ", result[(374, 375)]
print "(374, 375): ", result[(734,640)]
```

Results:

```
(374, 375):  2
(374, 375):  1
```

Comment: The problem is that this method does not show a list of items that has been repeated, for instance 734 has been followed by 640 once and by 1353 another time, but in the output it is shown that 734 has been followed by 1354 twice.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you want

```
    my_list = [372, 374, 375, 533, 849, 1057, 734, 640, 
               853, 2, 672, 581, 352, 384, 386, 505, 
               421, 372, 374, 375, 734, 1354, 1355
              ]

    adict = {}
    for k in range(len(my_list)-1):

        count = 0
        now_at = my_list[k]
        nxt_at = my_list[k+1]

        for i in range(len(my_list)-1):
            curr = my_list[i]
            nxt = my_list[i+1]

            if now_at == curr and nxt_at == nxt:
                count += 1
                adict[now_at] = (nxt_at , count)
```